# ImportError: No module named models

Tags: django, django-models

I am going a tad crazy here. I keep getting this error: ImportError: No module named models and I am not sure why. Here is what I have found so far...

```
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
>>> from mystore.cart import cart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Jeff/django/mystore/cart/cart.py", line 3, in <module>
  from mystore.cart.models import CartItem
ImportError: No module named models
>>>
```

I am not sure what's going on with this... line 3 in cart.py is this:

```
from mystore.cart.models import CartItem
```

If I try to do: from mystore.cart.models import CartItem it works fine...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing `from mystore.cart import cart`? That should be just `from mystore import cart`.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, you have a circular dependency: `mystore.cart.cart` is importing `mystore.cart.models`, which in turn is trying to import `mystore.cart.cart`.

You should determine if both of those imports are necessary, and if either of them could be moved out of the global scope into a function or method.

Answer (score 0):

Very early in the mystore.cart.models an error is occurring that's why nothing in models.py can be imported.  The error can be a circular import, a conditional statement that's triggered during runtime but not at the command prompt or is happening inside something else your are importing at the beginning of models.py

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a point before.

bad

```
from models import *
```

good

```
from .models import *
```

that means that is at the same level.